# JPA- Compound Primary Key using @EmbededId

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

**Goal**: To impolement an @Entity where the id is a compound primary key using @EmbededId.

**Problem**: Based on my current implementation, I am getting the following result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Recipe 1",
    "instruction": "Test Instruction",
    "note": "Note 1",
    "show": true,
    "createDate": null,
    "modify_date": null,
    "ingredient": [
      {},
      {}
    ]
  }
]
```

but I want to have this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Recipe 1",
    "instruction": "Test Instruction",
    "note": "Note 1",
    "show": true,
    "createDate": null,
    "modify_date": null,
    "ingredient": [
      {ingredient_id: 1,
       amount: 10},
      {ingredient_id: 2,
       amount: 20}
    ]
  }
]
```

Can someone please help me too see where I have done wrong in my recipeIngredient class? Thanks in advance.

**The following are my implementation:**

The schema:
[image]

RecipeIngredientId.java

```
@Embeddable
public class RecipeIngredientId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "recipe_id", nullable = false)
    private int recipeId;

    @Column(name = "ingredient_id", nullable = false)
    private int ingredientId;

    public RecipeIngredientId() {}

    public RecipeIngredientId(int recipeId, int ingredientId) {
        this.recipeId = recipeId;
        this.ingredientId = ingredientId;
    }
}
```

RecipeIngredient.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recipe_ingredient")
public class RecipeIngredient implements Serializable
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private RecipeIngredientId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ingredient_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Ingredient ingredient;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Recipe recipe;
    private double amount;

    public RecipeIngredient() {}

    public RecipeIngredient(Recipe recipe, Ingredient ingredient, double amount){
        this.recipe = recipe;
        this.ingredient = ingredient;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

Recipe.java:

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    private String instruction;
    private String note;

    @NotNull
    private boolean show;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date createDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "modify_date")
    private Date modify_date;

    private Set<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredients;

    public Recipe() {}

    public Recipe(String name, String instruction, String note, boolean show) {
        this.name = name;
        this.instruction = instruction;
        this.note = note;
        this.show = show;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getInstruction() {
        return instruction;
    }

    public void setInstruction(String instruction) {
        this.instruction = instruction;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public boolean isShow() {
        return show;
    }

    public void setShow(boolean show) {
        this.show = show;
    }

    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public Date getModify_date() {
        return modify_date;
    }

    public void setModify_date(Date modify_date) {
        this.modify_date = modify_date;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<RecipeIngredient> getIngredient() {
        return recipeIngredients;
    }

    public void setIngredient(Set<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredients) {
        this.recipeIngredients = recipeIngredients;
    }
}
```

Ingredient.java

```
@Entity
public class Ingredient {
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;

    private Set<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredients;

    public Ingredient() {}

    public Ingredient(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ingredient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<RecipeIngredient> getRecipeIngredients() {
        return recipeIngredients;
    }

    public void setRecipeIngredients(Set<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredients) {
        this.recipeIngredients = recipeIngredients;
    }
}
```

Comment: You included `RecipeIngredientId` but not `RecipeIngredient`. Also, you must annotate either all fields or all getters, not mixture; unless you use the `Access` annotation etc.

Comment: Hi @BrianVosburgh,

Sorry, I just realized that there's a missing class that I forgot to add. Please see the update

Comment: I have a solution that can work, but it will make it really hard for you to properly deserialize the JSON and persist it to the database if that's what you intend. The serialization part will be easy, though. That is, assuming you're using Jackson for it.

Comment: Hi @coladict, sorry about the late reply. I think this problem can be solved in using a very simple method but i i'm not sure since I am inexperienced with JPA.

Comment: And is the JSON serialization done with Jackson?

Comment: @coladict, yes, JSON serialization is done with Jackson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of "derived identity". `RecipeIngredient` should look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recipe_ingredient")
public class RecipeIngredient implements Serializable
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private RecipeIngredientId id;

    @MapsId("ingredientId") // maps ingredientId attribute of embedded id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ingredient_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Ingredient ingredient;

    @MapsId("recipeId") // maps recipeId attribute of embedded id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Recipe recipe;
    private double amount;

    public RecipeIngredient() {}

    public RecipeIngredient(Recipe recipe, Ingredient ingredient, double amount){
        this.recipe = recipe;
        this.ingredient = ingredient;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

Note the `MapsId` annotations on the two fields whose primary keys make up the entity's composite key.

Derived identities are discussed in the JPA 2.1 spec in section 2.4.1.